# why is my state not being set to the variable lat?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
let lon, lat;
let weather;
 if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
   lat = position.coords.latitude;
   lon = position.coords.longitude;
console.log(typeof lat)
 });
}
class Button extends React.Component{
state = {latt: lat}
  render(){
   return(
  <div>
{this.state.latt}
<h1>ss</h1>
</div>
   
)}}

class Appp extends React.Component {

 render(){
  return(
   <Button />
  )}
 }
ReactDOM.render(<Appp />, mountNode)
```

[what i did](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKh7R.png)

When I console.log the variable I get a number but why cant I use it as a value in state. Even putting it inside an array makes no difference.

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your question.  Working with external images is difficult.

Comment: Can you post your code here to help in debugging?

Comment: Your lat, lon will not be gaurented to be filled when the class is invoked as `getCurrentPosition` is not synchronous. Instead you should move this code with in the component and use `setState` to set lat and long.

Comment: alright ive added

Comment: how can i move it in component? it returns unexpected token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be this:

```
let lat, lon, weather;

class Calendar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            lat: null,
            lon: null
        }
        this.updateLatLon = this.updateLatLon.bind(this);
    }
    updateLatLon(){
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
                this.setState(() => {
                    return {lat: position.coords.latitude, lon: position.coords.longitude}
                });
            });
        }
    }
    componentWillMount(){
        this.updateLatLon();
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.lat}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: i think you meant constructor instead of construct. nevertheless both ways dont work

Comment: hm that should definitely work. I made some changes to the code that might make it work? not sure. try and tell me what kind of errors you're getting

Comment: youve forgotten to close the bracket after the navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition function. but still both ways arent working. it shows nothing the state is undefined

Comment: it shows nothing, even if i console.log it it still returns undefined on the console. it outputs nothing at all, have you tested this elsewhere and gotten correct results? what makes you say this is definitely valid?

Comment: I made a few changes, it should work now. I will test it on a local machine just to be sure but if this doesn't work then idk what's wrong

Comment: yup it works. There was something weird happening with scope, so I decided to set the state as soon as you get the coordinates. This way you don't even need to declare lat/lon variables.

Comment: wow, that works, thanks a lot :D btw can you explain what this line does this.updateLatLon = this.updateLatLon.bind(this); and why did you have to use constructor(props) and super(props)? why didnt you just write the updateLatLon function inside componentWillMount()

Comment: If you want a state you need to declare it in a constructor function. The line this.updateLatLon = this.updateLatLon.bind(this); sets the scope of the function so that the 'this' keyword always refers to the component in question. This is important, any function that calls this.setState needs to be bound in the constructor function

Answer (score 0):

You change the state by using `setState()`

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    this.setState({
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lon: position.coords.longitude
    });
    console.log(typeof lat)
});
```

Comment: where and when?

Comment: where am i supposed to add this? im getting unexpected token

Comment: Substitute the lines where you try to set `lat` and `lng` with this call.  This, in addition to actually defining the component's state fields (look in the constructor block of Robbie's answer to see what I'm talking about).  I also think it would help to surf the web for some sample React code to get a better understanding of the use of state.  Hope you've figured it out, and if not I'm happy to help!